# API when to use http headers for params

Tags: web-services, http-headers, jersey

I've been doing this Java backend for an iPhone app (Jersey REST mainly) and implemented some web services like sign up and log in. Obviously I've needed params like username and pin. Since this services change state in the DB I've made them as POST and I've used @FormParams Jersey annotation for the params. The guy who worked on client kept sending the username and pin in the headers and it took a little while to discover where's the problem.

is this the standard, to put authentication-like data in headers? How do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the standard http authentication mechanisms like Basic Authentication
then the credentials are sent in the http header

Something like this

```
POST /private/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

if you planning to expose this backend through an unsecure network, i would advise you to use https - as it encrpts your header

But if you are implementing your own authentication mechanism - then you can pass the credentials anywhere you like (header or body), that way- your backend would know where to look for the username and password.

check these links for reference
[Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) 
[http authentication](http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/)